# What is the physical meaning of integrating the output characteristic of a MOSFET?

Tags: transistors, power, mosfet

If I integrate the output characteristic of a MOSFET, calculating the surface area under the curve \$I_{ds}\$ - \$V_{ds}\$ at constant \$V_{gs}\$, what will be the physical meaning of the calculated value. Is it used power? dissipated power?...etc

Comment: **Why** would you want to integrate over that curve? The normal procedure to use mathematical operations (like integration) is to **first** describe a physical process (for example, charge buildup under the Gate) and then use mathematics to describe that, not the other way round. The world can be described by mathematics. Mathematics do not describe the world.

Comment: It is a meaningless quantity.

Comment: I will post the answer to why shortly, since I am experimenting.

Comment: The issue is that the values are discrete quantities, each point on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

If you take any point in the \$ V_{ds} \$ - \$I_{ds}\$ curve, you get the instantaneous power dissipation across the drain-source junction of the MOSTET for the given { \${V_{ds}, I_{ds}, V_{gs}}\$}. But if you integrate the curve, you get the area under the curve mathematically, which I don't think suggests any useful physical quantity to measure.

Comment: Indeed, since each point is on its own, I am making sure, that this is not reported yet ! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @ali_05 I look forward to your answer.